# Mounting virtual USB storage device for use in VMs

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtual-machine

I am looking for ways to mount a virtual USB storage device (containing some of my files) to several VMs (running Windows 7 and XP) on VMware.

So far, I have tried using ImDisk. ImDisk is capable of creating virtual disk drives but VMware does not recognise it as a USB device.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: VSphere or VM Player installed on a Desktop OS?

Comment: @Santeador I have VM Player installed

Comment: Need of "virtual USB" is a must? In VM Player Settings you can share a local folder with a VM. Have you tried to share the same folder with multiple VM?

Comment: @Santeador I am doing some testing with an autorun.inf file on a USB drive that I am required to run on a VM. There are restrictions to bringing USB devices in my workplace, so I am wondering if I could do it virtually.